# How to format an acknowledgements section in the LNCS template?

Tags: lncs, acknowledgements

The following is an excerpt from a paper published in some computer science conference proceedings that uses the [LNCS template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-lecture-notes-in-computer-science/kzwwpvhwnvfj#.WuA4JS5uZpi). How can I format an acknowledgements section like this in said template?

[image: Acknowledgements]

Comment: it just looks like a paragraph at the end of the text,  `...<blank line>\bigskip \noindent\textbf{Acknowledgements.} Jael....`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. Maybe you're right, but unlike a paragraph, there's no indentation.

Comment: I added `\noindent` in the comment above, or you could use `\paragraph*{Acknowlegements}` or more or less 1001 other forms.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The LNCS formatting guidelines at [link](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/conferences/DSVIS06/springer/typeinst.pdf) specify that the heading of the Ack section should be treated as a subsubsection heading and should not be assigned a number. So the solution is:

```
\subsubsection*{Acknowledgements}
```

Comment: Minor point for people who copy-paste the code: there is a missing dot, the correct code (as per the link) should be `\subsubsection*{Acknowledgements.}`